# List indicies must be integers. not str JSON reponse

Tags: python, json, string, list, parsing

I am baffled and do not know how to solve this error. I'm trying to grab every name inside a JSON response list.

My code looks like this.

```
def extract_strucutres_ids(expected_structures):
    response = requests.get(JIRA_REST + "/structures", verify=False)
    response = response.json()
    for structure in response['structures']:
        print structure['name']
```

The Json reponse looks like this.

```
{
    "structures": [{
            "id": 165,
            "name": "6.2 External Notifications Refactor",
            "description": ""
        }, {
            "id": 364,
            "name": "6.4 Day/Night Mode and Idle Scene Mode",
            "description": "",
            "readOnly": true
        }, {
            "id": 140,
            "name": "ACC 5 Regression",
            "description": ""
        }
    ]
}
```

I keep getting `List indicies must be integers, not str`.
Python version 2.7.10

Comment: please fix the typo first in `response['strucutres']`. Should be `structures`.

Comment: while `response` may _look_ like a dictionary, it is probably a string. This can be confirmed by printing the type of `response`: `print(type(response))`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

try this -

```
 import json

 def extract_strucutres_ids(expected_structures):
    response = requests.get(JIRA_REST + "/structures", verify=False)
    if response.status_code==200:
        response_json = json.loads(response.text)
        for structure in response_json['structures']:
           print structure['name']
    else:
        print("Response is {}".format(response.status_code))
```

Let me know,if it worked!

Answer (score 0):

Use `json.loads()`

```
response = requests.get(..)
response = json.loads(response.text) # response.text is a string
for structure in response['structures']: 
   # Do something
```

Comment: I get the error "expected string or buffer" in line response = json.loads(response.json())

Comment: @j.doe, modified my answer to use `response.text` instead